# PHP call_user_func vs. just calling function

Tags: php, function

I'm sure there's a very easy explanation for this.  What is the difference between this:

```
function barber($type){
    echo "You wanted a $type haircut, no problem\n";
}
call_user_func('barber', "mushroom");
call_user_func('barber', "shave");
```

... and this (and what are the benefits?):

```
function barber($type){
    echo "You wanted a $type haircut, no problem\n";
}
barber('mushroom');
barber('shave');
```

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Always use the actual function name when you know it.

`call_user_func` is for calling functions whose name you don't know ahead of time but it is much less efficient since the program has to lookup the function at runtime.

Comment: Thank-you Kai. call_user_func turned out to be exactly what I needed.

Comment: `call_user_func` is not necessarily needed. You can always call a function by using variable functions: `$some_func()`. `call_user_func_array` is the one that is really useful.

Comment: php always needs "to lookup the function at runtime"

Comment: call_user_func can also use pipes!

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan, You cannot, because there are **nameless** (anonymous) functions.

Comment: you can use it where you don't know either the function name of  its arguments.

Comment: @VolkerK, "always" is *always* wrong. It wholly depends on the PHP engine your server uses. Engines can be built to optimize `f()`, but it's a whole magnitude harder (indeed, it's close to hardly possible) to optimize `call_user_func($function_name)`

Comment: @Pacerier Incorrect. Anonymous functions are still in variables, i.e. `$func = function(){};`. Any possible parameter to call_user_func has to be callable, which means it contains enough data to access it directly, whether that's `$func()`, or `$obj->{$func}()`, or whatever.

Comment: The "less efficient" is actually very little, especially since php7, it's about few ms / million calls : https://github.com/fab2s/call_user_func

Comment: According to one [source](https://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/13084-call_user_func-vs-variable-functions), "calling a non-existing
function through a variable causes a fatal error, while
call_user_func() returns a warning." So that's one difference.

Answer (score 33):

Although you can call variable function names this way:

```
function printIt($str) { print($str); }

$funcname = 'printIt';
$funcname('Hello world!');
```

there are cases where you don't know how many arguments you're passing. Consider the following:

```
function someFunc() {
  $args = func_get_args();
  // do something
}

call_user_func_array('someFunc',array('one','two','three'));
```

It's also handy for calling static and object methods, respectively:

```
call_user_func(array('someClass','someFunc'),$arg);
call_user_func(array($myObj,'someFunc'),$arg);
```

Comment: I know this is ages old, but couldn't find articles elsewhere.  Is it more advantageous to use call_user_func('customFunction') as apposed to $variableFunction() ?  What are the differences?  Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

the `call_user_func` option is there so you can do things like:

```
$dynamicFunctionName = "barber";

call_user_func($dynamicFunctionName, 'mushroom');
```

where the `dynamicFunctionName` string could be more exciting and generated at run-time. You shouldn't use call_user_func unless you have to, because it is slower.

Comment: It seems like you could use a variable function in this scenario.

Answer (score 7):

With PHP 7 you can use the nicer variable-function syntax everywhere. It works with static/instance functions, and it can take an array of parameters. More info at https://trowski.com/2015/06/20/php-callable-paradox

```
$ret = $callable(...$params);
```

Comment: AFAICT, this is the only answer which really answers the question.

Answer (score 5):

I imagine it is useful for calling a function that you don't know the name of in advance...
Something like:

```
switch($value):
{
  case 7:
  $func = 'run';
  break;
  default:
  $func = 'stop';
  break;
}

call_user_func($func, 'stuff');
```

Comment: Nope. We can still do `$func('stuff');`

Comment: Yes, but the difference is using a variable will produce a PHP Fatal error versus a PHP warning if call_user_func is used.

Comment: This has not negated the value of variable functions over `call_user_func()` in this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

There are no benefits to call it like that, the word `user` mean it is for multiple user, it is useful to create modification without editing in core engine.

it used by wordpress to call user function in plugins

```
<?php
/* main.php */

require("core.php");
require("my_plugin.php");

the_content(); // "Hello I live in Tasikmalaya"
```

...

```
<?php
/* core.php */

$listFunc = array();
$content = "Hello I live in @@@";

function add_filter($fName, $funct)
{
    global $listFunc;
    $listFunc[$fName] = $funct;
}

function apply_filter($funct, $content)
{
    global $listFunc;
    foreach ($listFunc as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($key == $funct and is_callable($listFunc[$key]))
        {
            $content = call_user_func($listFunc[$key], $content);
        }
    }
    echo $content;
}

function the_content()
{
  global $content;
  $content = apply_filter('the_content', $content);
  echo $content;
}
```

....

```
<?php
/* my_plugin.php */

function changeMyLocation($content){
  return str_replace('@@@', 'Tasikmalaya', $content);
}

add_filter('the_content', 'changeMyLocation');
```

Answer (score 0):

in your first example you're using function name which is a string. it might come from outside or be determined on the fly. that is, you don't know what function will need to be run at the moment of the code creation.

Answer (score -2):

When using namespaces, call_user_func() is the only way to run a function you don't know the name of beforehand, for example:

```
$function = '\Utilities\SearchTools::getCurrency';
call_user_func($function,'USA');
```

If all your functions were in the same namespace, then it wouldn't be such an issue, as you could use something like this:

```
$function = 'getCurrency';
$function('USA');
```

Edit:
Following @Jannis saying that I'm wrong I did a little more testing, and wasn't having much luck:

```
<?php
namespace Foo {

    class Bar {
        public static function getBar() {
            return 'Bar';
        }
    }
    echo "<h1>Bar: ".\Foo\Bar::getBar()."</h1>";
    // outputs 'Bar: Bar'
    $function = '\Foo\Bar::getBar';
    echo "<h1>Bar: ".$function()."</h1>";
    // outputs 'Fatal error: Call to undefined function \Foo\Bar::getBar()'
    $function = '\Foo\Bar\getBar';
    echo "<h1>Bar: ".$function()."</h1>";
    // outputs 'Fatal error: Call to undefined function \foo\Bar\getBar()'
}
```

You can see the output results here: https://3v4l.org/iBERh it seems the second method works for PHP 7 onwards, but not PHP 5.6.

Comment: . for not being true. $fn = '\Foo\Bar\getCurrency'; $fn();

Comment: Hi @Jannis, I'm not finding that to be true, maybe you can see where I'm going wrong, I've added a more detailed example to my answer.

Comment: @ThomasRedstone did you required those functions beforehand? php do not autoload functions from other files. Also what's with that small vs big letters in namespaces. Is Bar a class? then that's another usecase.

Comment: hi @przemo_li, this is a single file (all within the namespace), not sure what happened with the namespace name, in my defence, I wrote the answer 4 years ago, I've updated the namespace, and added in a note about PHP 7, with a link to see the actual output. I still don't know how jansverre made it work, PHP 7 didn't enter alpha until 11 Jun 2015